# MySQL: Search group from constituent members using AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Following three SQL tables describe who belongs to which group. For example, Ann belongs to group A/B, Ben belongs to group B/C, and Chris belongs to group A/C.

Now, when I want to search "a group that both Ann AND Ben belong", how should we write the SELECT query? or should we design these tables in different way?

(1) users

```
+-----------+------------------+
| member_id | member_name      |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 | Ann              |
|         2 | Ben              |
|         3 | Chris            |
+-----------+------------------+
```

(2) groups

```
+-----------+------------------+
| group_id  | group_name       |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 | Group A          |
|         2 | Group B          |
|         3 | Group C          |
+-----------+------------------+
```

(3) users_groups

```
+-----------+------------------+
| group_id  | user_id          |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 |                1 |
|         2 |                1 |
|         2 |                2 |
|         3 |                2 |
|         1 |                3 |
|         3 |                3 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT group_id, group_name 
FROM groups
JOIN users_groups ON groups.group_id = users_groups.group_id
JOIN users ON users_groups.user_id = users.member_id
WHERE member_id = 1
INTERSECT 
SELECT group_id, group_name 
FROM groups
JOIN users_groups ON groups.group_id = users_groups.group_id
JOIN users ON users_groups.user_id = users.member_id
WHERE member_id = 2
```

This will give the group id and name of all groups where both Ann and Ben are in. Feel free to replace the member_id = # clause with member_name = 'name' if you want to search by their name instead of their id.

EDIT: I forgot that MySQL doesn't have INTERSECT. So the above will work for most DBMSs, but the below should return the desired results for MySQL.

```
SELECT groups.group_id, groups.group_name 
FROM groups
JOIN users_groups ON groups.group_id = users_groups.group_id
JOIN users ON users_groups.user_id = users.member_id
WHERE member_id = 1
AND groups.group_id IN (SELECT groups.group_id
                        FROM groups
                        JOIN users_groups ON groups.group_id = users_groups.group_id
                        JOIN users ON users_groups.user_id = users.member_id
                        WHERE member_id = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that we can not use "intersect" in MySQL. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that MySQL is.. Weird, as DBMSs go. I'll edit my answer with a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for alternative solution